# How to delay to fire a function

Tags: jquery

I have no experience with 'timeout's. I got these two steps I want to make on click:

```
close_layer();
$.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8);
```

I first want an delay of for example 1000 between these two actions. I tried using `delay` and `setTimeout`, but seems like I do not know how to use these properly.

I have tried:

```
close_layer().delay(1000);
$.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8);

//or 

close_layer();
setTimeout(1000);
$.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8);
```

I do not have any problems using delay, while I try to animate things. Which is irritating for me is the `$.fn.fullpage` which is generated by the plugin I use. What does the `$` at the beginning mean? Does it replace something like `$('this')` or is it a marker for a `global` function?

Comment: `$` is `jQuery` so that is `jQuery.fn.fullpage.moveTo()` which is equivalent to `Const.prototype.method = fn;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is an assynchronous function. You should use it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8); 
}, 1000);
```

In case you want to make sure `close_layer();` function is ended. You should either add a callback to this function and call it afterwards:

```
function close_layer(callback){
    ...
    callback();
}

function callback(){
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8); 
}
```

...or you can even try using [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/)

```
close_layer().then(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call the function after set time out end

```
   setTimeout( function() {
               $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8)
           },1000);
```

Comment: @JqueryKing  is close layer having any animation or set timeout function. or u can call this function at end of close layer

Answer (score 0):

try with callback

```
close_layer(callback);
```

in your close_layer function make sure you call the callback function like in the end

```
callback();

function callback(){
  setTimeout(function() {
     $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(8);
  },1000);
}
```